# Error when splitting and replacing chars C# email with LINQ Array Index not supported in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, c#-3.0

This throws an error 
'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
 so what would be an alternative for this as the split and replace fails?

```
from S in db.Students
where S.ID = ID
select new { S.EMAIL.Split('@')[0].Replace(".", " ,"), S.NAME };
```

This is for a list of Students and this is how I currently can add them.

```
mylist.DataValueField = "email";
mylist.DataTextField = "name";
```

This fails:

```
S.EMAIL.Split('@')[0].Replace(".", " ,")
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to run on the SQL server you can use IndexOf and Substring:

```
from S in db.Students
where S.ID = ID
select new 
{ 
    EMAIL = (S.EMAIL.Contains("@") ? 
                S.EMAIL.Substring(0, S.EMAIL.IndexOf("@")) : 
                S.EMAIL
            ).Replace(".", " ,")
  , S.NAME 
};
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Max(Int32, Int32)' method,

Comment: Hmm, it works in LinqToSql. It can be removed as it is already guarded by the contains.

Comment: I found an alternative with two replace instead of split. Removing the tail after @ and then replacing the '.'. Your answer though right wouldn't work in my case.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following

```
var query =  (from S in db.Students
             where S.ID = ID
             select new { 
                 S.EMAIL, 
                 S.NAME })
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(x => new {
                  EMAIL = x.EMAIL.Split('@')[0].Replace(".", " ,"), 
                  NAME = x.NAME});
```

So that the splitting and replacing is done in linq to objects instead of the DB.