# How do I get quoted fields from a delimited string as a list of unquoted values using LINQ?

Tags: c#, string, linq, char, delimiter

Original text line is:
`"125"|"Bio Methyl"|"99991"|"OPT12"|"CB"|"1"|"12"|"5"|"23"`

Expected string list is free of double quotes and split by `|`:

```
125
Bio Methyl
99991
```

The text may contain empty quoted strings as in (former "OPT12" value now empty ""):

```
"125"|"Bio Methyl"|"99991"|""|"CB"|"1"|"12"|"5"|"23"
```

So I checked these two questions & answers :[QA1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4366422/2061309) and [QA2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29540398) to derive my solution.

```
var eList = uEList.ElementAt(i).Split(BarDelimiter);
var xList = eList.ElementAt(0).Where(char.IsDigit).ToList();
```

Of course it doesn't work the way I need it to be since `xList` is a list with elements like this: `xList(0) = 1, xList(1) = 2, xList(2) = 5`

I do not want to write another line to join them because this doesn't look like a suitable solution. There has to be something better with LINQ right?

Comment: I just edited the question to make the title a bit more precise and searchable and I added the requirement to support empty quoted values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
// Based on OPs comment: preserve empty non-quoted entries.
var splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.None;
//change to the below if empty entries should be removed
//var splitOptions = StringSplitOptions.None;
var line = "\"125\"|\"Bio Methyl\"|\"99991\"|\"OPT12\"|\"CB\"|\"1\"|\"12\"|\"5\"|\"23\"";
var result = line
    .Split(new[] { "|" }, splitOptions)
    .Select(p => p.Trim('\"'))
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

The `Split(...)` statement splits the input into an array with parts like

```
{ \"99991\", \"OPT12\", ... };
```

The `p.Trim('\"')` statement removes the leading and trailing quote from each of the parts.

Comment: @GrantWinney true, with both separators included and no empty quoted elements like "".

Comment: `RemoveEmptyEntries` Specifies whether applicable String.Split method overloads include or omit empty substrings from the return value. So it can't be used as empty values must be preserved e.g. *OPT12 column can be empty*.

Comment: I am perplexed about the behaviour of [`RemoveEmptyEntries` ...The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When I tested it, this actually includes empty values...any idea why?

Comment: Yes, they are not empty when performing the split, so "abc"|""|"defg" will be split as an array with quoted strings: { "abc", "", "defg" }. In the next step the call to `p.Trim("\"")` will remove the quotes, so you end up with an empty string.

Comment: That's a good one. And I chose yours as the solution. However given the comment to @Pierre, can you give me some performance-wise insights comparing yours to his?

Comment: Both of them should be pretty similar I think. They will likely do around the same amount of string allocations. The split + trim combination will do less searching, but I doubt that it will make any difference in practice.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the trimming, if there's no `"` in your values, you could simply sanitize the input before splitting it. You can do so by replacing the `"` symbol by nothing (either `""` or `string.Empty`).

Your `Split` code would then give the correct result afterwards:

```
string uEList = "\"125\"|\"Bio Methyl\"|\"99991\"|\"OPT12\"|\"CB\"|\"1\"|\"12\"|\"5\"|\"23\"";
var eList = uEList.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Split(BarDelimiter);
```

Comment: I tried yours and @Alex solutions. Both works fine. However performance-wise I need your help to explain to me know which one gives optimized results, why or how, (because this is a function that will be repeated within loops for enormous times)